# Size and usage of lookup table in cryptographic schemes

Tags: implementation, performance

I would like to understand the typical size of a lookup table for software implementations of a cryptographic scheme.

1. What size is considered reasonable?
2. What make them (in)efficient?
3. Are there heuristics to determine (without implementing anything) if a table will become interesting?

Comment: What is a cryptographic lookup table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very / too generic question:

> **Q1: What size is considered reasonable?**

Any size that fits easily in the CPU cache(s) of the target platform. Otherwise it depends on the memory requirements for the algorithm in general.

> **Q2: What make them (in)efficient?**

If the CPU data cache needs to be refreshed continuously then they may slow down the algorithm and, if you're unlucky, leak side channel information as well.

> **Q3: Are there heuristics to determine (without implementing anything) if a table will become interesting?**

Probably not as it depends a lot on specifics of the underlying platform.

In general lookup tables are used to speedup calculations, so as long as the resulting implementation is faster, you're in business.

But note that there may be security implications when using them, all depending on what is being implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As regards question 3, for instance, I was wondering if a table that can fit only in L3 cache but not in L2, nor L1, could produce a significant performance gain?

Comment: There is one way to find out: try. Because it certainly depends on what it is that it is replacing. If that (partial) algorithm is fast then probably not; if it is slow then it may be worth the cost. All caches are not created equal either.